# Why are my parachutes failing to deploy?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I have 3 parachutes on my plane's tail, and I'm trying to deploy them while the plane is landing. However, when I deploy the parachutes in sequence, all 3 fail to deploy.

This is my scenario:

- The plane has touched the ground and is moving.
- The brakes are being applied to stop the plane.
- The engine throttle is either set to 0, or the engines are completely off.

Yet when I deploy it in mid-air while the engine is on, all 3 parachutes successfully deploy (suspending the plane in mid-air).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because parachutes automatically cut once the craft touches the ground or water in vanilla game. To make proper drogue chutes, you'll need a mod, whose name eludes me at the moment.

Comment: [RealChute](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/57988-0-23-x-RealChute-Parachute-Systems-Presets!-v1-1-0-1-27-04-14), right?

Comment: That'd be the one, if I recall correctly. It's been a while since I last played Kerbals.